# Separated Boxplots for each column of a dataset

Tags: r, apply, boxplot

I have a data frame with 79 columns.

For each column, I am trying to produce an entirely separated boxplot.

I have tried
`apply(integers, 2,function(x) boxplot(x, main = colnames(integers["x"])))`

However, I cannot add the title of each column to the respective boxplot.

Comment: Have you tried `names(x)`?

Comment: I have tried names(x) and a few other options. I do get my individual plots, however, the plots remain without title.

Comment: In that case just use a regular loop with indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)


plot_function <- function(column_name, data_in) {

  plot_out <- ggplot(data_in, aes_string(y = column_name)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    labs(title = column_name)
  return(plot_out)

}

plot_columns <- names(iris)[1:4]

plot <- lapply(plot_columns, function(x, y) plot_function(x, y), y = iris)
plot[[1]]
```